# "related process is still running." Error while installing Domino FixPack

Tags: windows-server-2003, ibm-domino

I have Domino Server configured to run on startup.  I quit the server and it still is warning.  I then set the Diagnositcs and Server services to manual and restarted, and I'm still getting the same warning.

Any ideas on what else to do to get a FixPack to install?  I'm trying to install on Windows Server and I don't see any processes starting with a w or n that look suspicious.  As I mentioned, I've rebooted as well to try and ensure file locks are cleare dup.

Comment: `I have Domino Server` - my condolences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the .exe file as Administrator. Right click on the file and choose "Run as Administrator"

If that desn't help, then look for an antivirus or backup program. They could lock some of the files.

Comment: Yup, that was the isssue.  I had found out and tried to answer, but there's a 8 hour window.  I wish the warning wasn't so misleading.

Comment: In our cases this is always the AntiVirus which is causing such issues. When we stop this service everything was running fine.